# How to change the types of vertices of the first and second kind in bipartite graph?

Tags: r, igraph, bipartite

***I want to make a network of countries by co-participation in film production, but with my code, I have the reverse result (films by countries).***

I read that "Bipartite graphs have a ‘type’ vertex attribute in igraph, this is boolean and FALSE for the vertices of the first kind and TRUE for vertices of the second kind." So, I think that I should change the types of vertices, but don`t know how.

Unfortunately, the data is in the closed access, so it is impossible to download it, but the final matrix (a) has countries as columns and films ids as rows. I also tried to flip the df, but it didn`t help (the vertices in the graph were countries as I wanted, but there were no connections between them).

```
#I load df and make some changes with it 
  movies <- read_csv("~/shared/mi_2018/data/movies.csv") %>% 
  select(movie_id, production_countries)
  movies_with_countries = extract_json2(df = movies, col = "production_countries")
  a = spread(movies_with_countries, key = production_countries_sep, 
  value = production_countries_v)
  row.names(a) <- a$movie_id
  a = a %>% select(-movie_id, -production_countries)
  a[is.na(a)] <- 0

 #Here I make a bipartite graph, but the result is reverse compared to what I expected
  bg = graph.incidence(a)
  V(bg)$type
  pr = bipartite.projection(bg)
  q = get.adjacency(pr$proj1,sparse=FALSE,attr="weight")
  plot(pr$proj1,edge.width=E(pr$proj1)$weight^2,edge.color="black",vertex.label=V(pr$proj1)$name)
```

***I expect the graph to represent the connection of countries by their co-participation in film production, but in the actual graph is about fils connected based on countries.***

Comment: Could you please make a small sample data set to illustrate your problem?

Comment: #Matrix
s = matrix(c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0), nrow=3, ncol=4)
bg2 = graph.incidence(s)
V(bg2)$type

Comment: #Network                                                                                                              
pr2 = bipartite.projection(bg2)
q2 = get.adjacency(pr2$proj1,sparse=FALSE,attr="weight")
plot(pr2$proj1,edge.width=E(pr2$proj1)$weight^2,edge.color="black",vertex.label=V(pr2$proj1)$name)

Comment: Here I also have raws (1,2,3) as vertices of the graph, but I need columns (V1, V2, V3, V4) to be vertices that are connected by raws. When I rotated the matrix by 90 degrees, I got the graph I need, but there were no links between nodes(I made links grey and the whole background was grey).

Comment: Code should be an [edit] in the question, not in comments where it's very hard to read or debug